# Npm run dev " commands don't work on windows

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, push-notification, npm-install

Laravel Version: 5.4.1
PHP Version: 5.6
node v8.9.3
npm v5.5.1
Description:
npm commands are completely broken on windows (windows 7 in this case), whenever I run npm run dev I get the following error:

'node_modules' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

**My package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
   "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
},
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.2",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.1.10"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "laravel-echo": "^1.3.3",
    "pusher-js": "^4.2.2"
  }
}
```

and showing error

```
> @ dev c:\wamp\www\web
> node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.co
nfig.js

path.js:7
    throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' + inspect(path));
    ^

TypeError: Path must be a string. Received undefined
    at assertPath (path.js:7:11)
    at Object.parse (path.js:950:5)
    at new File (c:\wamp\www\web\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\File.js:14:30)
    at Object.module.exports.preprocess (c:\wamp\www\web\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\index.js:108:14)
    at Object.module.exports.sass (c:\wamp\www\web\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\index.js:84:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\wamp\www\web\webpack.mix.js:17:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Mix.initialize (c:\wamp\www\flores\node_modules\laravel-mix\src\Mix.js:38:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\wamp\www\flores\node_modules\laravel-mix\setup\webpack.config.js:18:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
```

i have searched or spent much more time on it but no success on that if any one have idea plese let me know thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Enclose all your path references in your scripts with escaped double quotes, i.e. `\”path/to/something.js\”`

For example:

```
...
"scripts": {
    ...
    "development": "NODE_ENV=development \”node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js\” --progress --hide-modules --config=\”node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js\”",
    ...
},
...
```